# LocalStorage sumar valores

Tags: javascript, local-storage

Cree una key que va guardando el valor anterior; y quiero sumar el valor anterior al nuevo valor (todo ingresado por el mismo input);

por ej: tengo 5  y al ingresar 2 quiero obener 7;

Pero solo me reemplaza el valor por ej: si ingreso 5 como 1er valor lo guarda; al ingresar 2 me reemplaza a 5 y la suma me devuelve 4 como resultado final y si ingreso 3 un 6.

Espero sea entendible la pregunta muchas gracias desde ya por la ayuda

```javascript
function assert() {
    let valorDeInput = document.getElementById('btn2').value;
    localStorage.setItem('name_user', valorDeInput);
    let user = localStorage.getItem('name_user');
    let suma =  parseFloat(' valorDeInput') + parseFloat (user);
    document.getElementById('cuadrado').innerHTML = suma;
}
```

***Quiero obtener la suma de los 2 valores y no que se reenplace***

Comment: Espero estar respondiendo bien y en el lugar correcto.....para que los mas expertos no se ofendan; me sirvio la respuesta de Cesar ya le di el boton correcto....espero tengan paciencia es la 1er vez que utilizo stack

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Se reemplaza porque estás guardando el valor nuevo antes de obtenerlo. Lo ideal sería que obtengas el valor del storage, lo sumes y finalmente guardes el resultado.

```
function assert() {
    let valorDeInput = document.getElementById('btn2').value;
    let user = localStorage.getItem('name_user');
    let suma =  parseFloat(valorDeInput) + parseFloat (user);
    document.getElementById('cuadrado').innerHTML = suma;
    localStorage.setItem('name_user', suma);
}
```